# Open one div per call

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like that when I open a div, all the others close himself. I've looked for around and I found only answer with jQuery and not JavaScript.

This is my code:

```js
function openDescription(description_id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(description_id);
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } 
};
```

```css
.row_team_pic{
  text-align:center;
  margin:-72px;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.container{
  background-color:silver;
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.photo{
    min-height:125px;
    width:125px;
    margin:10px;
    padding-top:10px;  
}

.name{
  text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.description1{
  float:left;
  margin-left:0%;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:silver;
  width:322px;
}
.description2{
  float:left;
  margin-left:-57%;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:silver;
  width:322px;
}
.description3{
  float:left;
  margin-left:-57%;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:silver;
  width:322px;
}
.description4{
  float:left;
  margin-left:-114%;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:silver;
  width:322px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row_team_pic" id="riga1">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
  </div>
  <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description1')">Name1</div>
  <div class="description1" id="description1_id" style="display:none">
    It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
          It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
  </div>
  <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description2_id')">Name2</div>
  <div class="description2" id="description2_id" style="display:none">
    It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
          It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
  </div>
  <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description3_id')">Name3</div>
  <div class="description3" id="description3_id" style="display:none">
    It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
          It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
  </div>
  <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description4_id')">Name4</div>
  <div class="description4" id="description4_id" style="display:none">
    It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
          It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
  </div>
</div>
```

For example if I click on `name2` it give me the `description2`, but if I click on `name3` it doesn't close the `description2` but overlap only.
How should I achieve that?

Comment: where's the `body` element?

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal I don't have any `<head>` tag so I neather put a `<body>` tag because all the code should be in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new class called `description` into all the div elements which has the description. Then in your function, if the element's style is not `display: block`, hide all the elements that have the class `description` and set the `display: block` property to only to the selected element.

```js
function openDescription(description_id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(description_id);
        
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('description');

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                elements[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            x.style.display = "block";
        } 
   };
```

```css
.row_team_pic{
    text-align:center;
    margin:-72px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.container{
    background-color:silver;
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.photo{
    min-height:125px;
    width:125px;
    margin:10px;
    padding-top:10px;  
}

.name{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.description1{
    float:left;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
.description2{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-57%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
.description3{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-57%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
.description4{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-114%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row_team_pic" id="riga1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description1_id')">Name1</div>
    <div class="description description1" id="description1_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description2_id')">Name2</div>
    <div class="description description2" id="description2_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description3_id')">Name3</div>
    <div class="description description3" id="description3_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description4_id')">Name4</div>
    <div class="description description4" id="description4_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the function you have to reset `display = none` to all the div having class name started with `description` except the clicked element. Then set `display = block` only to the div whose `id` is passed to the function.

To achieve that add the following code inside the function:

```
var allNames = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=description]');
allNames.forEach(function(d){
  if(d.getAttribute('id') != description_id){
    d.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

**Working Code:**

```js
function openDescription(description_id) {
  var allNames = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=description]');
  allNames.forEach(function(d){
    if(d.getAttribute('id') != description_id){
     d.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
  var x = document.getElementById(description_id);
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } 
};
```

```css
.row_team_pic{
    text-align:center;
    margin:-72px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.container{
    background-color:silver;
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.photo{
    min-height:125px;
    width:125px;
    margin:10px;
    padding-top:10px;  
}

.name{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.description1{
    float:left;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
.description2{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-57%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
.description3{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-57%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
.description4{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-114%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:silver;
    width:322px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row_team_pic" id="riga1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description1_id')">Name1</div>
    <div class="description1" id="description1_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description2_id')">Name2</div>
    <div class="description2" id="description2_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description3_id')">Name3</div>
    <div class="description3" id="description3_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="" width="125" height="125"/>
    </div>
    <div class="name" onclick="openDescription('description4_id')">Name4</div>
    <div class="description4" id="description4_id" style="display:none">
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
        It's ok. It's working. It's ok. It's working. 
    </div>
</div>
```